# Why there are no female nude scenes in satirical sex comedy film?

Tags: production, orgazmo

*Orgazmo (1997) UNCUT* is a comedy movie about porn shootings.

But it doesn't contain female nude scenes (main thing is missing) but it contains male nude scenes.

Why are there are no female nude scenes in a satirical sex comedy film?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I'm having a hard time trying to figure out why there would *have to be* female nude scenes, which is what your premise seems to imply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Spoiler alert:** I haven't seen this movie myself.

I can understand why someone (especially a straight man) would expect female nudity to be present in a movie "about porn."  Movies about porn are supposed to be erotic and (at least for straight men) female nudity is erotic.  It may not be *politically correct* to assume that, but I'm sure many people would think so anyway (they may not *say it* but they'd at least *think it.*)

I also know satire is a very sarcastic form of comedy - it thrives on making its point by doing or saying the exact opposite thing.

So, a satirical film "about porn" which only includes male nudity is probably trying to make a point about how ridiculous (the White Knights among us might even say "sexist") it is for you - the viewing audience - to have come into this movie *expecting to see boobies.*

In other words, the *whole point* of the movie was to challenge the very assumption you (and many others, I'm sure) have made.

**This is not intended to be a personal attack on you,** OP, simply an explanation.  I very likely would have walked into this movie expecting the same thing, if I'm being honest.  I would have walked out chuckling at myself for having assumed something like that, and ultimately would have learned a lesson about how I should approach similar subject matter in the future.  Hopefully, you can do the same, and not take this movie too personally for it.